# Creating table, column can not be null when other one is, and the way around

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a table for my own dummy purposes, but I want it to be as follows:

2 columns, Open and Paid. When paid is 0/null, open has to be 1000. When open is null/0 paid has to be 1000. I'm not sure how to bake this into a CREATE TABLE statement! Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Normally you don't put that kind of logic in your DB. You do it at application level

Comment: Do you have existing data that you want to initialize this table with, or is this logic for future incoming data?  You don't bake that into a `CREATE TABLE` statement with only those 2 columns.  You would either need computed columns or you would need to create the table and then fill it based off of existing data and your logic.  Going forward you can create a trigger with your logic to handle future data.

Comment: @squillman Since the question is how to do this in a CREATE TABLE statement, I think it pretty much has to be only for new data, since tables that don't exist yet don't usually have any data in them.

Comment: @TabAlleman Reason I ask is because I'm wondering if the real need would be for a `SELECT..INTO` instead of a `CREATE TABLE` since OP states the table is for dummy purposes.

Comment: you did not say if both fields can be 0/null at the same time. Can they ? And what if they are ?

Comment: Sounds to me like using two columns is the wrong thing. A bit datatype sounds more appropriate here. No matter how you slice it the design of your table sounds off.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a [CHECK CONSTRAINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-2017) in your CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right you want either both columns can have a different value than `0/null` or when one has `0/null` the other should be `1000` ?

This can be done with a check constraint like this :

```
create table #test (
  [Open] int null,
  Paid int null,

  constraint CK_Values check ( (isnull([Open], 0) <> 0) and (isnull([Paid], 0) <> 0)
                               or
                               ((isnull([Open], 0) = 0 and Paid is not null and Paid = 1000) or (isnull([Paid], 0) = 0 and [Open] is not null and [Open] = 1000))
                             )  
)

insert into #test values (1, 2)       -- success
insert into #test values (0, 1000)    -- success
insert into #test values (null, 1000) -- success
insert into #test values (1000, 0)    -- success
insert into #test values (1000, null) -- success

insert into #test values (0, 2)       -- fails
insert into #test values (null, 2)    -- fails
insert into #test values (2, 0)       -- fails
insert into #test values (2, null)    -- fails
insert into #test values (null, null) -- fails
insert into #test values (0, 0)       -- fails
```

Answer (score -1):

You won't be able to make this using only a `create table` statement. You also need a trigger (after update and after insert) if you want to make it work. Also, you will need to define what would happen if you insert or update `0` or `null` to both columns at the same time.

If your table is:

```
create table dummy (your_pk int primary key, open numeric(18,2), paid numeric(18,2));
```

You can use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dummy_trg_ins 
ON  dummy  
AFTER INSERT 
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE dummy
    SET paid = 1000
    FROM Tb
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.your_pk = dummy.your_pk
    WHERE i.open is null or i.open = 0
    UPDATE dummy
    SET open = 1000
    FROM Tb
    INNER JOIN inserted i on i.your_pk = dummy.your_pk
    WHERE i.paid is null or i.paid = 0
END  
GO
```

Similarly, you will need an update trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dummy_trg_upd 
ON  dummy 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE dummy
    SET paid = 1000
    FROM Tb
    INNER JOIN updated i on i.your_pk = dummy.your_pk
    WHERE i.open is null or i.open = 0
    UPDATE dummy
    SET open = 1000
    FROM Tb
    INNER JOIN updated i on i.your_pk = dummy.your_pk
    WHERE i.paid is null or i.paid = 0
END  
GO
```

Comment: Using a trigger for this would be somewhat overkill and hinder performance. Row versioning and version store would kick in as I recall for using an After trigger.